# Sitecore_Analytics_Index is Broken

Tags: experience-analytics, experience-profile

I am getting zero results in Sitecore Experience Dashboard and found that Sitecore gets data using Sitecore_analytics_index and an analytics index that i have is more or less broken, and as far as I know it is not possible to trigger a rebuild of the index.

Can somebody please let me know how do i rebuild Sitecore_analytics_index and i have already build reporting Database which didn't result in success

Comment: Version of Sitecore?

Comment: Its 8.1 Update 2

Comment: Check https://vladimirhil.com/2017/05/16/rebuild-sitecore-analytics-index-without-re-building-reporting-database/

Comment: Before you rebuilt your analytics DB, did you clear out the analytics index by deleting ll the the files in the index folder?

Comment: No I didn't clear it let me clear it and do it again.

Answer (score 1):

The Sitecore recommended way to rebuild the sitecore analytics index is to rebuild the reporting database. To achieve this, you also need to delete the index files in the index folder. For Lucene, you can find that in the `\Data\indexes\sitecore_analytics_index` folder.

When the rebuild is complete, the analytics job will run and rebuild the index.

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/81/sitecore-experience-platform/en/walkthrough--rebuilding-the-reporting-database.html